# Comparing Dates with optional "comparison values"

Tags: java, date, time, compare, comparison

I would like to compare the current date with the following optional variables which will be provided (multiple can be used): Year, Month, Day, Hours, Minutes, Seconds.

Possible comparison operators would be "before", "after" or "equals" - for single-variable comparisons a beforeOrEquals, afterOrEquals operator would be helpful as well.

**Here are two examples how it would work:**

If only the year is set, it would only check if the year is before/after the current year. If both the year and the month is set, it would consider both year and month in the comparisons.

The **special thing with this comparison** is if, for example, only the month is set, but not the year. In that case, the 21. February 2020 should be before the 21. March 2020 but AFTER the 21. January 2021.

For the current date, a LocalDateTime will be used. The comparison values (year, month etc.) are Integers. If they are -1, they should not be compared (= they are not provided).

This is how I'm currently doing the comparison:

```java
    public final boolean compare(){
        //These values will need to be changed accordingly before the comparison. I have my own way of letting the user provide them as input.
        int year = -1;
        int month = -1;
        int day = -1;
        int hours = -1;
        int minutes = -1;
        int seconds = -1;
        String operation = "";
        String timeZone = null;

        final LocalDateTime currentTime = timeZone == null ? LocalDateTime.now() : LocalDateTime.now(timeZone.toZoneId());


        final LocalDateTime timeToCompare = LocalDateTime.of(
                year > -1 ? year  : currentTime.getYear(),
                month > -1 ? month : currentTime.getMonthValue(),
                day > -1 ? day : currentTime.getDayOfMonth(),
                hours > -1 ? hours : currentTime.getHour(),
                minutes > -1 ? minutes : currentTime.getMinute(),
                seconds > -1 ? seconds : currentTime.getSecond()
        );

        if(operation.equals("before")){
            if(!currentTime.isBefore(timeToCompare)){
                return false;
            }
        } else if(operation.equals("after")){
            if(!currentTime.isAfter(timeToCompare)){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Is this a good way of implementing it, or is there a more performant way, since not every variable needs to be compared at all?

Comment: This site is not a code-writing service, and you’ve provided none. We can help you with *specific* questions about *your* code, ideally accompanied by an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That said, most of your needs can be met using classes from the `java.time` package

Comment: Also, your function is underdefined since it needs to be antisymmetric (i.e., give consistent results if you swap the order of the operands, which might have differing levels of detail).

Comment: Thank you, I have added my own attempt of implementing this to my original question. The order of the operands shouldn't actually matter at all and give the same result no matter the order. For where the variables are inputted, I actually let the user input the variables in any random order

Comment: `LocalDateTime` does not allow "blank" values such a `-1` for any of its fields. But `java.time` has classes for all the time fields, eg `Day`, `Month`, `Year`, etc. I would create a class with fields using each of these as their type and have a `compareTo()` method that still works when any of them are `null`.

Comment: @Bohemian Since it doesn't allow blank values, I have just used the current time instead of blank values in `LocalDateTime`, which shoould work correctly. Would an own class with its own `Day`, `Month`, `Year` etc. fields still be better there? And how would the `compareTo()` implementation work approximately - can I use some methods from `java.time` as help there, or would I need to implement it from scratch to support null values?

Comment: @Ookami I don't think using current values will work for "blank" fields; an object with a blank field is fundamentally different from one that has a value for that field.

Comment: Oh as for "semantics" it wouldn't make sense, yeah. But I'd use that object with current values as temporary object only, so I can use the java.time methods to do the comparison for me. Wouldn't the end result be correct?

Comment: Misuse of a class in contradiction to its documented semantics is *abuse* of a class. You most definitely should write your own class, as suggested in Answer by Bohemian.

Answer (score 2):

I would apply the [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) principle:

```
record PartialDateTime (Integer year, Integer month, Integer day, Integer hour, Integer minute, Integer second) 
        implements Comparable<PartialDateTime> {

    public int compareTo(PartialDateTime other) {
        // your impl here
    }

    public boolean isBefore(PartialDateTime other) {
        return compareTo(other) < 0;
    }

    // etc for other truthy comparison methods
}
```